# Is it possible to auto logout sudo after a period of inactivity?

Tags: linux, sudo

Often times when I gain root via `sudo -s` I'll end out doing something else for a while and totally forget that I've logged in.

Is there a way to just de-sudo after some amount of time of inactivity? I've found something like `TMOUT=3600` in some blog posts, but that appears to be a little more general than I'm looking for.

Is there a way to drop sudo privileges after a period of inactivity?

Comment: Why not set it when running `sudo`?

Comment: If you directly execute the commands with `sudo` instead of doing `sudo -s`, after the timeout `sudo` will again ask for the password. If you insist on getting a root shell, using a wrapper to start this shell together with an `at` command to kill it shouldn't be too hard to set up.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio pointed out, I can just set it when running sudo, so I can do something like:

```
$ sudo -s
# export TMOUT=3600
# do stuff ...
# <do nothing for a while>
```

The only problem is that I *do* have to have exited to the shell, but that's not a huge deal